# Best way to keep consistency using mapping-table

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with a table named `TIRE` where I save some informations about tires, another table named `VEHICLE` and is where all vehicle information is placed.

I also need to map what tire is associate with what vehicle and in what position.
For cover that scenario I have a table called `VEHICLE_TIRE`.

Here is the structure of the tables (simplified to only cover my problem):

TIRE:

```
ID | GARAGE_ID
```

VEHICLE:

```
ID | PLATE_NUMBER | GARAGE_ID
```

VEHICLE_TIRE

```
VEHICLE_ID | TIRE_ID | TIRE_POSITION
```

Every client has multiple garages where his vehicles stays. They need to know in what garage their tires and vehicles are. That is covered by the `GARAGE_ID` column. Tires are not necessarely associated to a vehicle (no entry for this tire in the `VEHICLE_TIRE`) because it could be a stock tire of a particularly garage.

At any moment, the client is able to transfer vehicles and tires among his garages in the system. Of course, if he transfer a vehicle, all his associated tires must be transfered as well. The client is also able to disassociate a tire from a vehicle and transfer only this specific tire.

My question is, how can I ensure, in DB level, that the tires associate with a vehicle are always in the same garage and prevent a state where a tire is in one garage and the vehicle is in another (different garage_ids).

The only solution I came with is to use a trigger in both tables, `VEHICLE` and `TIRE`, to ensure in every UPDATE that this inconsistency does not happen.

Another thing to consider is that the `VEHICLE` and `TIRE` tables are huge tables shared for all clients and updates are frequently, so I'm concerned with the overhead that my solution would add.

Can I achieve the same purpose using another approach?

*EDIT:*

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dd81f) with solution using unique constraints.

Updates like this are blocked: `UPDATE VEHICLE_TIRE SET VEHICLE_ID = 2 WHERE VEHICLE_ID = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `garage_id` to `vehicle_tire`, add `garage_id` to the primary keys of `tire` and `vehicle` (or add a new unique constraint).

Then you can add `garage_id` to the foreign keys, and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Interesting solution. I used the unique constraints and is working great. Thanks!